# Is it safe to let users define angular expressions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security

In my angular application I would like to let users define advanced filter expressions to filter the objects that are displayed. I was looking at different libraries, and it seems that [filtrex](https://github.com/joewalnes/filtrex) is doing what I want, but the amount of expressions that it allows might not be enough for my purpose.

I was thinking to simply use angular expressions instead. I would instantiate a new angular module (to be sure that no filters or rootScope variables defined in my application can become a problem), and simply run `$parse` in it.

As the filter expressions defined by my users will be saved in the application and be run when other users open the application, it is crucial that no harmful code can be entered in the filter expression.

Thus my question is: Are angular expressions safe to be defined by users? Or do they allow in any way to do something harmful, such as modifying the dom, redirecting to another page, making HTTP requests, or something else that I cannot think of now?

Comment: Quoting the [Angular security page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security): **'If an attacker has access to control Angular templates or expressions, they can exploit an Angular application via an XSS attack, regardless of the version'**. In other words: not a good plan.

Comment: I can't say anything specific as to Angular, because I'm unfamiliar with it, but if you're allowing your users to save code, to which other users are then exposed, it's inherently unsafe. Assume your users are hostile, malicious and know how to expose and exploit flaws in the system you're presenting. That said, could you not implement this as an API of some sort, that way you can verify and validate server-side.

Comment: @JoeClay: Interesting. But I still wonder if they are only talking about the case where the scope in which the expressions are evaluated is used in a template, in which case it is obvious to me how the expressions could be used in a bad way. In my case, the expressions would be run in an isolated angular module, and I wonder if in that case it is also possible to exploit the expressions.

Comment: The page I linked states that calling `$parse` on user content is exploitable (under 'Passing an expression generated from user-provided content in calls to services that parse expressions'). By the sounds of it, you'd basically be giving the user free reign to run arbitrary JS on your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Angular security guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security), user-provided expressions should never be executed.

Until Angular 1.5, expressions were executed in a sandbox, in order to prevent poor programming styles (not to prevent security holes). In every version of Angular, ways to escape the sandbox have been found. Many examples can be found by searching the web for `angular sandbox escape`, and a short overview over the issue can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/bughunteruniversity/nonvuln/angularjs-expression-sandbox-bypass).

In Angular 1.6, the sandbox [has been removed](http://angularjs.blogspot.com.tr/2016/09/angular-16-expression-sandbox-removal.html), so running arbitrary JavaScript from expressions should be even easier.

So letting users define angular expressions is absolutely not safe.